# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Hello friends I wnat to integrate `GCM` in my app so I set following code in my app:

**On button click call function**

```
public void requestForGCM(final Context context ){
    try {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            };
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                regid = null;
                try {
                    if (gcmObj == null) {
                        gcmObj = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcmObj.register("SENDER_ID");
                    Log.w("", "Token >> "+regid);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", "requestForGCM  >> "+e.toString());
                    return null;
                }
                return regid;
            }

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                try {
                    String GCMToken = result;
                    etRegId.setText(regid + "\n");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", "onPostExecute >> "+e.toString());
                }

            }
        }.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "requestForGCM >> "+e.toString());
    }
 }
```

i set jar as below
[image]

[image]

[image]

When I run above code it gives me error like as follows:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging
```

**EDIT LOGCAT**

```
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at pkg.android.rootways.worldofrental.FragmentDashboard$8.doInBackground(FragmentDashboard.java:1142)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at pkg.android.rootways.worldofrental.FragmentDashboard$8.doInBackground(FragmentDashboard.java:1)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-08 11:37:20.193: E/AndroidRuntime(10385):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Any solution, how can I solve this problem? your all suggestion are applicable

Comment: can you post your whole log

Comment: Why you have defined `jar` file for support library as well as you have added the `project` both. Define any of the one.

Comment: Clairvoyant : see my whole logcat

Comment: What's your SDK version?

Comment: SilentKnight  : my sdk version is 22 but that is not issue i already make a demo with same sdk and it is working but when i integrate in my application that it is not working

Answer (score 0):

When Adding referenced libraries we need only google-play-services_lib.jar.So that we need to remove the library project from your project.

Project->Properties->javaBuildPath->Project->select google-play-services->remove.

clean and build.

Comment: PAD : i did same as you told but same issue occured